# How to get an array of indices of minimum values for a multimensional array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a multimensionnal array with a shape of (2, 2, 3) like this :

```
array([[[  0.64,   0.49,   2.56],
    [  7.84,  13.69,  21.16]],

   [[ 33.64,  44.89,  57.76],
    [ 77.44,  94.09, 112.36]]])
```

I would like to find the indices of the min for each row. So for this example there are 4 minimums which are : 0.49, 7.84, 33.64 and 77.44.

To get the indices of those minimum I thought this would work :

```
idx_arr = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(my_array,axis=2),my_array.shape)
```

This yields the following array of indices :

```
(array([[0, 0],
    [0, 0]]), array([[0, 0],
    [0, 0]]), array([[1, 0],
    [0, 0]]))
```

However, the minimums are not correctly computed, as one can see :

```
my_array[idx_arr]
array([[0.49, 0.64],
   [0.64, 0.64]])
```

What am I missing there ?

Answer (score 1):

the argmin is actually calculating the values correctly. But you misunderstand what [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) is expecting.

From docs:

> Converts a flat index or array of flat indices into a tuple of
>   coordinate arrays.

To see what kind of input it would accept to give the desired output here, We need to focus on the main point: it will convert a flat array into the correct coordinate array for a particular location in non-flat terms. Essentially, what it expected is coordinates of your desired points *as if* your input array was flattened.

```
import numpy as np
inp = np.array([[[  0.64,   0.49,   2.56],
    [  7.84,  13.69,  21.16]],

   [[ 33.64,  44.89,  57.76],
    [ 77.44,  94.09, 112.36]]])

idx = inp.argmin(axis=-1)
#Output:
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Note that you cannot send this `idx` directly because it is not representing correct coordinates for a flattened version of `inp` array.

That would look more like the following:

```
flat_idx = np.arange(0, idx.size*inp.shape[-1], inp.shape[-1]) + idx.flatten()
#Output:
array([1, 3, 6, 9], dtype=int64)
```

And we can see `unravel_index` accepts it happily.

```
temp = np.unravel_index(flat_idx, inp.shape)
#Output:
(array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64))

inp[temp]
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.49,  7.84, 33.64, 77.44])
```

Also, taking a look at the output tuple, we can notice that it is not too difficult to recreate the same ourselves as well. Notice that the last array corresponds to a flattened form of `idx`, while the first two arrays essentially enable indexing through the first two axes of `inp`.

---

And to prepare that, we can actually use the `unravel_index` function in a rather nifty way, as follows:

```
real_idx = (*np.unravel_index(np.arange(idx.size), idx.shape), idx.flatten())
inp[real_idx]
#Output:
array([ 0.49,  7.84, 33.64, 77.44])
```